# How to debug API response using MVVM Android Architecture

Tags: mvvm, observable, retrofit2, android-databinding, android-livedata

I was trying to fetch data from a remote API, following MVVM and [Google Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html) Pattern with:

- LiveData
- Retrofit 2
- Dagger 2
- Observable
- Databinding

My question is:

> How can I debug the Api response?

In my last project (using Asynctask, retrofit and GSON) I can stop in the moment when the Api response, so I could see the header of the response if it was a 200 response or 404. Then I could see the json of the Api response, etc...

[Using this repo](https://github.com/iammert/AndroidArchitecture) I can't see anything of what I said above, for example, I don't know if the data received was ok or if the model is filled with the JSON response.

I don't gonna copy and paste the code because I'm learning with the repo above and I think that my question **is more theoretical**.

Anybody has felt like me with this new pattern and architecture?

Anybody can help me solving my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) is the best tool for tracking API responses and DB changes.

First you have to init it in your Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
  }
}
```

Then add it to your OkHttp client:

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
    .build();
```

Finally open Chrome, then type

> chrome://inspect/#devices